# Why SYCL supports openCL 1.2 or above?

Tags: tensorflow, opencl, gpu, opencl-c

I am a student. My question may be very silly but I want to clear it. I have a device with Vivante GPU with openCL 1.1 version. I want to run tensorflow sample code with SYCL support on GPU. But before trying Tensorflow sample code, I want to try SYCL sample code with openCL 1.1 on GPU.

I have seen several SYCL implementations, like computeCPP, triSYCL, [sycl-gtx](https://github.com/ProGTX/sycl-gtx). **All the implementations support openCL 1.2 or above.**

Does anyone know the reason why SYCL doesn't support openCL 1.1?

And how feasible will it be the attempt to modify the SYCL open-source code to support openCL 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason for SYCL 1.2 to require OpenCL 1.2 is because the Khronos intermediate representation [SPIR 1.2 requires](https://www.khronos.org/faq/spir) it. Without SPIR, or any other intermediate representation, a SYCL implementation cannot compile C++ code into device binaries, and would need to convert C++ to OpenCL C, which is quite problematic.

Comment: thank you so much for yours response. I seen a image here http://techenablement.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/WideningOpenCLEcoSystem.png which depicts the possibility of no intermediate representation like SPIR between opencl and SYCL.

Comment: And what is major difference that makes openCL 1.1 to be not supported by the SPIR representation?

Comment: Since I want to run tensorflow code on GPU with openCL 1.1, how should I start against the problems? What should I try to code to get success in this?

Comment: You can use the interop mode of SYCL to dispatch OpenCL C kernels instead of C++ kernels, but that will reduce what you can do with SYCL. In particular, you cannot use the TensorFlow approach.